The degree of the field extension $\mathbb{C}(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}(x^3+x^{-3})$.
I am asked to find the degree of the field extension $L:=\mathbb{C}(x)$ over $K:=\mathbb{C}(x^3+x^{-3})$.
My attempt:
Let $f(Y):=Y^6-(x^3+x^{-3})Y^3+1$. It has roots:
$$ x,wx,w^2x,x^{-1},wx^{-1},w^2x^{-1}$$
in $L$, where $w$ is the primitive $3$-rd root of unity.
I want to show that $f$ is irreducible over $K$, so that $[L:K]=\deg f=6$. Assume by contradiction that $f$ is reducible, then either
$$ x^i\in K,\quad i\in \{-2,-1,1,2\}$$
or
$$ x+ax^{-1}\in K,\quad a\in \mathbb{C}$$
It seems that both cases are absurd, but how to argue this? Or if there is any quick way to compute this?
Thanks for your help!

You could  (should?) have also edited the earlier variant of this question into shape instead of deleting and reposting. The material you added to this version would have gotten the first version reopened and upvoted rather speedily. That is the preferred practice on Math.SE simply because deleted questions do not really disappear. Guess I could still find (at a least a moderator could do that). And negatively received questions may lead to question bans and such. Unlikely in your case, because you have earned enough rep, but total noobs sometimes fall for that :-(.

If you have covered Artin's lemma(s) and friends, then you can combine the following facts. Prove/justify them! Think of this as an extended hint.

$L=K(x)$, so $n:=[L:K]=\deg m(Y)$, where $m(Y)\in  K[Y]$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$.
The map $x\mapsto 1/x$ can be extended to a $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$.
The map $x\mapsto wx$ can be extended to a $K$-automorphism $\tau$ of $L$.
The group $G$ of $K$-automorphisms generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ has order six. Why does this give a lower bound $[L:K]\ge6$?
Why does your polynomial $f(Y)$ yield an upper bound $[L:K]\le 6$?
List everything about $[L:K]$ and $Gal(L/K)$ that follows from all of the above.


Not saying that this would necessarily be the shortest route to the destination. It is the one I would follow, but you do need Artin's lemma and such to get the fourth bullet. The second and the third bullets are either easy or a bit taxing; depending on whether you have covered the $\Bbb{C}$-automorphisms of $L$. When I teach Galois theory, those would be covered before this exercise, but other teachers/books may go about it differently.

Thank you very much professor! I have another approach to explain the fourth bullet: Since $\left\langle \sigma,\tau \right\rangle\leqslant \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ and $L/K$ is a Galois extension, we have: $[L:K]=|  \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)|\geqslant 6$.
(This explanation use the equivalent definitions of Galois extension, hence also need Artin lemma?)

This fact is needed to get the second and the third bullets. I could not immediately find a variant of that question covering the $\Bbb{C}$-automorphisms of $L$ even though it is standard.

May be you don't need Artin's lemma, because it is, indeed, easy to show by other means that $L/K$ is Galois.

For the second and third bullet, I also find exercise 4.10 in Serge Lang's Algebra helpful.

You could note that $\mathbb{C}(x^3 + x^{-3})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x^3)$, so its elements must be rational functions in $x^3$, which the elements you point to are clearly not. This can be shown rigorously by defining the degree of a rational function, and showing that the degree of your elements are not a multiples of $3$, like they would have to be in $\mathbb{C}(x^3)$.

Thank you! I got it.
